# Reporting Service 2012 Cross-tab Horizontal Report

Tags: reporting-services, crosstab, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

I am new to Reporting Services 2012 and struggling to design a report that should be quite "simple". At least, it is in excel. I am confused as to how to approach this problem. I have attached a sample pdf of what I want. It is basically a report on annual and half-yearly Qty Sold, Amount and Average Price. It then has the same (Qty, AMount and AVg.) for the year as well.

However, unlike conventional reports, this expands horizontally, instead of vertically. Since Product info is completely suppressed, the row labels need to be shown to the left. It is difficult to explain exactly what I want - hence I have attached a sample pdf (created from excel) to make it clearer. As you can see it's quite simple.

What I am struggling with is how to even get started? If I use a Matrix (crosstab), then the Qty Sold, Amount, Avg. labels go to the column. I don't even know what to include in the Row Group.

One possible way that it might work is if I get my data in the following format:

`| Label      | Year  | Half  | Value   |
|------------|-------|-------|---------|
|Qty Sold    | Y1    |  H1   |    q1   |
|Amount      | Y1    |  H1   |    a1   |
|Avg. Price  | Y1    |  H1   |    ap1  |
|Qty Sold    | Y1    |  H2   |    q2   |
|Amount      | Y1    |  H2   |    a2   |
|Avg. Price  | Y1    |  H2   |    ap2  |
|Qty Sold    | Y2    |  H1   |    q3   |
|Amount      | Y2    |  H1   |    a3   |
|Avg. Price  | Y2    |  H1   |    ap3  |
|Qty Sold    | Y2    |  H2   |    q4   |
|Amount      | Y2    |  H2   |    a4   |
|Avg. Price  | Y2    |  H2   |    ap4  |`

However, that is a complete hack and getting Yearly Totals probably wouldn't work in this manner!
Would appreciate any guideline to get started.

Thanks in advance!

[SampleReport.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekphm5am1yfodmo/Sample%20Report.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Add a row group for each row you want (Qty Sold, Amount etc) Group on "A" or something similar.
Add Column groups for half and year and drag Qty Sold into the value area for the first row group, Amount for the second etc...